# Can I use 'in' for defining time in the past?

Tags: prepositions, past-tense, prepositional-phrases

I thought that 'in' shouldn't be used for defining time period in the past, instead 'after' or 'later' should be used

Excerption from the [book](http://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/texts/fiction/mm.aspx):

> **In half an hour** Lake called us again *(past simple)*

Question:

Can I use 'in' for defining time in the past? If it's some exception, I would appreciate your examples of these cases

Comment: Authors are not required to follow grammatical "rules". Any native English speaker will read Lovecraft's sentence and understand, without giving it any thought, that his intended meaning is _"After thirty minutes had passed, Lake called us again."_ Authors often make choices for reasons of style and rhythm—they don't write with a book of grammar at their side.

Comment: I agee with @P.E.Dant. The normal expression I would expect would be "Half an hour later". To me, using the expression "in half an hour", which is normally confined to non-past use, gives the narrative an immediacy similar to using the historic present (even though the writer did not do that).

Answer (score 2):

**In half an hour** does not refer there to a past time. It refers to a *duration* of time unconnected to any particular timeline.  In other words, "in half an hour" means "within a span of time lasting 30 minutes".

> **In only one day**, they had the barn built with the help of their community.
>
> I had a bad headache yesterday and took some ibuprofen tablets. **In twenty minutes**, I was feeling better.